# Lebesgue measure of the set of zeroes of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $B_t(w)$ be a Brownian associated with a measure $P(dw)$. Suppose that $X$ is a random set of times $t$ where $0 \le t \le 1$ such that $B_t=0$. Show that $X$ has Lebesgue measure zero $P$ almost surely.

Comment: "P almost everywhere" >> "P almost surely".

Answer (score 5):

$E(\int_Xdt) = E(\int_0^1 \chi_{B_t = 0} dt) = \int_0^1 E(\chi_{B_t = 0})dt = \int_0^1 0dt = 0$. So $\int_Xdt = 0$ almost surely

Answer (score 0):

This holds for every jointly measurable process $(A_t)_t$ such that $P[A_t=0]=0$ for every $t$. In turn, this condition holds as soon as the distribution of every $A_t$ is densitable.

To see why, consider the maximal possible set $X$, namely, $Z=\{t\mid A_t=0\}$, define $L=\mathrm{Leb}(Z)$, and use Fubini to get
$$
E[L]=E\left(\int \mathbf 1_{t\in Z}\mathrm dt\right)=\int P[t\in Z]\mathrm dt=\int P[A_t=0]\mathrm dt=\int 0\,\mathrm dt=0.
$$
Since $L\geqslant0$ almost surely, the fact that $E[L]=0$ implies that $P[L=0]=1$, that is, that $L=0$ $P$-almost surely.