# Standard Brownian motion almost surely not $0$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

Consider a continuous standard brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$. I want to show, that $$\mathcal{L}(\{t\ge 0: B_t=0\})=0$$

I also have a hint that I need to show that $B:\mathbb{R}_+\times\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Then I shall find, that $E[\mathcal{L}(\{t\ge 0: B_t=0\})]=0$ and conclude the statemate above. I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem? Which kind of measurability do you have to show?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589020/lebesgue-measure-of-the-set-of-zeroes-of-brownian-motion

Comment: Well, of course any $B(t,\cdot):\Omega\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and, since the paths are continuous any $B(\cdot,\omega):\mathbb{R}_+\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable as well. But does this already imply measurability of $X$? Maybe I can express some $B^{-1}(Z)$ as an union of such $B(\cdot,\omega)^{-1}(Z)$ and $B(t,\cdot)^{-1}(Z)$. And maybe, since the paths are continuous, it is sufficient to consider $t\in\mathbb{Q}$.